# Capturing a picture and than displaying within an ImageView - Android

Tags: android

Hey guys I am using my webcam to simulate a camera in the emulator and when I go to take the picture and select the check mark button to use the picture I run across an error while trying to display the image back into my `ImageView` on the app.

Here is my code:

Initiator:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

function....

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) { 
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                    //OI FILE Manager
               filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                    //MEDIA GALLERY
               selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);


               img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

               imagePath.getBytes();

               Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

               Log.w("Here","error");

                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gimg1);
                image.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

            }
   }
}
```

I run across a `runtime error`

Suggestions and thoughts are needed!

Comment: Just updated the function to include where data is coming from....waiting on log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(requestCode==CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtra("data");
        image_taken.setImageBitmap(image);
}
```

You were calling `data.getData()` whereas it should have been `data.getExtra("data")` as `data` is an `intent` which you will have put the `bitmap`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(requestCode==CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gimg1);

        image.setImageBitmap(image);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following codes. It's fully functional and allows you set image from both your camera and gallery as well. I am almost sure that your runtime error is "OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget" as I am seeing that you have loaded the captured image directly to your imageView. You should scale it , please take a look at the method called GetScaledBitmap in my following code. Hope your codes will work ok if you use that method only when you load the image to your imageview. Full example is done for you , Hope it helps.

```
package com.tseg.android.mctemplate;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.tseg.android.mctemplate.R;

public class PhotoTake extends Activity {
    Button add1 ;
    ImageView img1 ;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_PHOTOS = 0;
    private static final String PACKAGE = "spine";

    Uri mCapturedImageURI;

    private int photo_count = 0;
    boolean hasPhotos = false;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String[] paths;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo);

        add1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add1);
        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);

        add1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ShowDialog(100, 1000);
            }
        });
    }



    void ShowDialog(final int req, final int choose) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("");
        builder.setTitle("Select Photo")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Take Photo",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {                                
                                File pictureFileDir = getDir();
                                if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

                                    Log.d("Photo Take", "Can't create directory to save image.");
                                    Toast.makeText(PhotoTake.this , "Can't create directory to save image.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    return;
                                }

                                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
                                String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                                String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";
                                String filepath = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator;
                                File imageFile = new File(filepath , photoFile);

                                ContentValues image = new ContentValues();

                                image.put(Images.Media.TITLE, photoFile);
                                image.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, photoFile);
                                image.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Accident data Accachment " + date);
                                image.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, date);
                                image.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, date);
                                image.put(Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, date);
                                image.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                                image.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);

                                 File parent = imageFile.getParentFile();
                                 String path = parent.toString().toLowerCase();
                                 String name = parent.getName().toLowerCase();
                                 image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, path.hashCode());
                                 image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
                                 image.put(Images.Media.SIZE, imageFile.length());

                                 image.put(Images.Media.DATA, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                                 mCapturedImageURI = PhotoTake.this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image);


                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                        mCapturedImageURI);

                                startActivityForResult(intent, req);

                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton("Choose Existing",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
                                        intent, "Complete action using"),
                                        choose);
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // From camera

        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (mCapturedImageURI != null) {
                img1.setImageBitmap(getScaledBitmap(mCapturedImageURI));;
                System.out.println("Onactivity Result uri = " + mCapturedImageURI.toString());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PhotoTake.this, "Error getting Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        //From gallery
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                System.out.println("Content Path : " + selectedImage.toString());

                if (selectedImage != null) {
                    img1.setImageBitmap(getScaledBitmap(selectedImage));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PhotoTake.this, "Error getting Image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }           
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(PhotoTake.this, "No Photo Selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        File imgFile = new File(path);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return myBitmap;
    }


    public String getPath(Uri photoUri) {

        String filePath = "";
        if (photoUri != null) {
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return filePath;
    }

    private File getDir() {
        File sdDir = Environment
          .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return new File(sdDir, "SpineAttachments");
    }

    private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Uri uri){
        Bitmap thumb = null ;
        try {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            InputStream in = cr.openInputStream(uri);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize=8;
            thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(PhotoTake.this , "File not found" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return thumb ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya the above suggestions worked great, definitely appreciate you're code :)

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple way to Click button and set store image in imageview.

> `public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 22;

Uri cameraUri;

Button BtnSelectImage;
private ImageView ImgPhoto;
private String Camerapath ;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    BtnSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    BtnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                   startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't load photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        switch (requestCode) {
       case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                      Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

                      ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);    

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't load photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}`

Set this Manifest.

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
>      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"></uses-feature>`